# Issue ploting data and linear basis using matlines

Tags: r, plot, statistics, spline, piecewise

I'm trying to get a linear basis to be plotted one the same graph as my data points and predicted model however I am not able to figure out how to combine the two using the `matlines` and `matplot` functions in R. Here is the code that I am using,

```
require(faraway)
require(splines)
data(exa, package="faraway")

matplot(bs(exa$x,10,degree=1),type="l",ylab="")
lmod <- lm(y ~ bs(x,10,degree=1),exa)
plot(y ~ x, exa, col=gray(0.75))
lines(predict(lmod) ~ x, exa, lty=2)
matlines(bs(exa$x,10,degree=1),predict(lmod) ,type="l",ylab="")
```

Which produces the following two plots,
[image]

The first plot is what I expect it to be however the second plot seems very distorted and I cannot figure out how to get the second plot to display properly. It appears that the axis is somehow distorted as I am expecting the linear basis to be plotted on the x-axis. I am expecting the second plot to appear something similar to this,
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably just confused by the formula notation. In the plotting sequence you always want the same `x=`.

```
with(exa, plot(x=x, y=y, col=gray(0.75), pch=20))
with(exa, lines(x=x, y=predict(lmod), lty=2))
with(exa, matlines(x=x, y=bs(x, 10, degree=1), type="l", ylab=""))
```

[image]